# How to Cursor & Add Hover effect using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, mouseover

I want to add Custom set of cursor on my website. I have added that cursor but while hover anything that cursor change  I have the Set of Pointers including both .ani & .cur required for my site. I have already tried :

This is the JavaScript that I used !

```
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.cursor = "url('cursor/blue.cur'), auto";
</script>
```

My cursor:

[bluecursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1zTp.png)

I have its Set , but I dunno the code to set while cursor for crosshair ,help , wait etc.

[cursorset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SchUa.png)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

All supported cursors can be enabled through CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this with javascript it seems as a bether idea to have a class in your css with the desired behaviour/style and then only set that class with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me (not JS but jQuery):

```
$("body").css('cursor', 'url(arrow_blue.cur) , auto');

$(".button").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('cursor', 'url(arrow_blue.cur) , auto');
});
```

Don't forget to override if there is any specific items like buttons, etc... Just defining a cursor for body does not cover the elements under, if something special is defined for them. So you have to override, for mouseover etc...

Comment: thanks this code is working gud. but what if i havent stated any specific item , i directly used <a href="index.php"><img src="styles/home.png" alt="INDEX" ></a> how can i change hover mouse pointer then ?

Comment: @Cruz Dusk infact a:hover is overriden by default with pointer, yo do not need to define something for that, browser automatically makes it pointer when comes over <a> tag. So by default <a> tag is one of those specific elements, which overrides the default cursor. So we have to override the 'overriden (i mean pointer)' cursor. So again we should use this code for tag a's hover effect. We can use this:                                        $('a:hover').css('cursor', 'url(arrow_blue.cur), auto');

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, it is better to do it in css:

For example, if you wanted to have the cursor change to your custom cursor only when hovering over an anchor tag then you can do this:

```
a {
  cursor: url(cursor/bluecursor.cur), auto;
}
```

If you wanted to have the cursor ALWAYS use custom cursors, then you have to decide when to use a special cursor.  You can do this with classes:

```
.help {
  cursor: url(cursor/help.cur), auto;
}
```

Then apply that class to the particular element that you want to display the custom cursor:

```
<div class="help">Help Me</div>
```

There is no way (to my knowledge) to simply tell the browser just replace all cursors with a custom set.